# Date calculations in C#

Tags: c#, date

I have a date as string in the following format:

```
yyyy-mm-dd
```

e.g.

```
2011-08-29
```

I want to check two dates and see if date1 is smaller than date2.

pseudocode:

```
string date1 = "2011-08-29";
string date2 = "2011-09-29";

if (date1 < date2) {
    MessageBox.Show("First date is smaller!");
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? The `yyyy-mm-dd` format indeed allows to correctly compare dates using raw strings...

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Well.. of course I did try it before asking the question. However I got the following error: `Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'`

Comment: you would use `date1.CompareTo(date2) < 0` if you really want to do comparison on the strings

Comment: As a matter of fact, one rationale for making YYYY-MM-DD the ISO 8601 recommended date format is, that it has a lexicographic order and allows easy sorting.

Comment: @Luther Blissett: that's why I choose that format. However since my `date1 < date2` didn't work I thought I couldn't do string comparison as a solution.

Comment: @PeeHaa, I see. Indeed, the relational operators are not defined for strings in C# (but they are in VB.NET IIRC).

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Well... same goes for PHP, but it was a C# question ;)

Comment: @PeeHaa So are you asking how to compare strings in C#? Use String.Compare method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's guaranteed that the dates are always in that exact format, a string comparison is sufficient.

Comment: It will always be in that format. That's why I choose that format. However I get an error if I try to compare them. See my comment under the question.

Comment: See Daniel Hilgarth's comment to your comment.  You need to use the CompareTo function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 12, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert both your strings to DateTime variables and use `DateTime.CompareTo` found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya.aspx

Use `Convert.ToDateTime(date1)` to convert.

Solution could look like

```
If (Convert.ToDateTime(date1).CompareTo(Convert.ToDateTime(date2)) < 0){
MessageBox.Show("First date is smaller!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `DateTime` object by parsing that string and then continue with that logic.
Ex:

```
DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.Parse(date1);
```

for safe parsing, the `DateTime.TryParse(date1, out dateTime1)`

Answer (score 1):

If the dates are in `YYYY-mm-dd` format, there is no need for parsing. Your example is working perfectly well.

Comment: it isn't. Please see my comment under the question.